# Getting a list output to write correctly in rows in a csv file

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to write this output to a csv file but it is simply not working. I have tried many writing to csv tutorials but none of them work. If you could please direct me to tutorial explaining why this isnt working, I would like to learn the issue and solve it.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

myurl = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38'

uclient = ureq(myurl)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
items = page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'item-container'})

#filename = 'zeus.csv'
#f = open(filename, 'w')
#header = 'Item Details\n'

#f.write(header)

#contain = items[0]
#container = items[0]
for container in items:
    details = container.a.img['title']
    with open('zeus.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(details + "\n")
    #print(details)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run

```
with open('zeus.csv', 'w') as f:
    for container in items:
        details = container.a.img['title']
        f.write("{} \n ".format(details))
```

The problems that were in the code are that with open('zeus.csv', 'w') as f: was in the loop so in each iteration it is overwritten the previous iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that for writing list to .csv file :

```
import csv

#open file
with open(..., 'w', newline='') as your_file:
     writer = csv.writer(your_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

     # write your list values
     writer.writerow(your_list)
```

Comment: this outputs the entire text, letter by letter, of the last line of the output into the in the csv file as the cells in the first row. why is this happening. each cell has one letter of the last line of the output.